# Using C++ Libraries on Linux

Tags: c++, ubuntu, compilation

I'm trying to follow along [here](https://github.com/flashlight/wav2letter/wiki/Inference-Run-Examples) to use a speech recognition model. The model is in C++, and almost all of my experience is in Python.

I installed a virtual machine running Ubuntu, and still the installation procedure was failing for me. I decided to simply try to **compile the model so that I could call it in a Python script**, as seen at the bottom of the linked page.

I'm trying to use g++ to compile the `.cpp` model, but I keep getting an error saying that a library that I have installed is not found:

```bash
name@name-virtual-machine:~/Documents/<PATH_TO_FILE>$ g++ InteractiveStreamingASRExample.cpp 
In file included from InteractiveStreamingASRExample.cpp:70:
cereal/archives/binary.hpp:43:10: fatal error: cereal/macros.hpp: No such file or directory
   43 | #include <cereal/macros.hpp>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
```

I tried simply putting the file in my directory and using parentheses rather than angled brackets, but this caused further issues down the line.

My bin folder contains a "cereal.bin" file, but no "cereal" folder.

Does anyone know how to resolve this issue? It would be much appreciated - I've been trying to get this working for a day

Comment: "a library that I have installed is not found" *how* have you installed it?

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. I installed using `sudo apt-get install cereal`

Comment: You've installed only the runtime libraries. You also have to install the development version (e.g. header files), most likely called something like `cereal-devel` or so. I am no ubuntu nor cereal expert, best you consult the documentation of your system about the package names.

Comment: It's [libcereal-dev](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/libcereal-dev)

Comment: @ErdalKüçük thank you! If you'd like to leave an answer I can accept it

Comment: @AlanBirtles thank you!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've installed only the runtime libraries. You also have to install the development version (e.g. header files), most likely called something like cereal-devel or so.

Alan Birtles provided a link to the development packages in the comments section above.

https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/libcereal-dev